# Trying to implement Exclude manually, getting different results

Tags: typescript

I've just got started with Typescript, learning the basics. The thing is I'm not able to wrap my head around how `extends` works in this case. This is how the built-in Exclude works, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2c458c0d1ccb96442bca9ce43aa987fb0becf8a9/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1439.

I am trying to manually implement it without any success.

I tried the below code sample on Typescript playground. Getting different results (See the comments). Can anyone explain why this discrepancy?

```js
type FirstSet = 1 | 3 | 4
type SecondSet = 1 | 3 | 2

type ManualImplementation = FirstSet extends SecondSet ? never : FirstSet;

type LibraryExclude = Exclude<FirstSet, SecondSet>

const b: LibraryExclude = 4; // works fine anything other than 4 leads to type error.

const c: ManualImplementation = 1; // all values from FirstSet works just fine.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to know, how things are implemented. One has to know what 'distributive conditional types' in Typescript to understand what is going on in the above code sample.

In this blog post: https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/, it's explained thoroughly. The mistake in my code is I have to pass `type` variables also to make it work.

```js
type ManualImplementation<A, B> = A extends B ? never : A;
const c: ManualImplementation<FirstSet, SecondSet> = 1; // Type error ;)
```